# What is the difference between the [co-dominium-series] and [mote-series] tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

Five questions are tagged [mote-series](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mote-series). One of those questions is also tagged [co-dominium-series](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/co-dominium-series). Checking Wikipedia, *[The Mote in God's Eye](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mote_in_God%27s_Eye)* is a novel that is part of the [CoDominium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CoDominium) series, which itself is apparently subdivided into several series, including a "Moties series." Nothing on Wikipedia is named "Mote Series."

Both tags clearly relate to the series which contain *The Mote in God's Eye*, but I'm not familiar with the books and I don't know what the tag names should be.

- Do we need both [mote-series](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mote-series) and [co-dominium-series](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/co-dominium-series), or should one be merged into the other?
- Should [mote-series](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mote-series) be renamed to [moties-series](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moties-series)?
- Should [co-dominium-series](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/co-dominium-series) be renamed to [codominium-series](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/codominium-series) (without the first hyphen)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit of research has convinced me the term "Mote series" *is* used, and is in fact more common than "Moties series". The search terms ["Mote series" Jerry Pournelle](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22mote+series%22+jerry+purnelle&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=8uQEV8KnCcHwUJXOs7AG#q=%22mote+series%22+jerry+pournelle) yield 7200 results on Google, while ["Moties series" Jerry Pournelle](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22moties+series%22+jerry+pournelle&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=t-UEV5iyBIOBU9n9v5AN) yield only 500-odd. Given that the terminology used by Wikipedia will actually skew results towards "Moties series" (since so many other websites copy Wikipedia's content, any phrase used on Wikipedia will generate hundreds of hits from that fact alone), I think this means that **"Mote series" is by far the more popular term**.

The main books in the Mote series are [*The Mote in God's Eye*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mote_in_God%27s_Eye), [*The Gripping Hand*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Gripping_Hand), and *Outies* - the latter being an authorised sequel written by Jerry Pournelle's daughter and marketed as "Mote Series, Book 3" (it's even mentioned as such on [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CoDominium) you linked to).

Meanwhile, the term "CoDominion series" seems to refer to all works set within the imagined history that begins with an alliance (the CoDominium) between the USA and a revived USSR, who manage to colonise various planets before the alliance breaks down. Most of these books are written or co-written by Jerry Pournelle, but they don't form a single unified series, more a collection of works which are vaguely connected by being set within the same universe. As far as I can understand, though, the Mote series does form a coherent and unified narrative.

So, let's consider your bullet-pointed suggestions:

- > Do we need both [mote-series](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mote-series) and [co-dominium-series](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/co-dominium-series), or should one be merged into the other?

  **Yes, let's keep them both.** There aren't very many questions on either of them at the moment, but that could change, and there's plenty of precedent for having one tag for the wider series or universe and more tags for sub-collections of works within that.

  However, it might be worth hunting around for more questions to tag with [codominium-series](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/codominium-series). This tag is only used on one question so far, but there may be others (not necessarily [mote-series](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mote-series) questions) which deserve the tag.
- > - Should [mote-series](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mote-series) be renamed to [moties-series](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moties-series)?

  **No.** However, when you write a tag wiki for [mote-series](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mote-series) (as I'm sure you plan to do shortly), it's worth mentioning that it can also be called the Moties series. I don't think there's any point in setting up a synonym either, since when people type `mot` into the tag box they'll get this tag via autocomplete anyway.
- > - Should [co-dominium-series](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/co-dominium-series) be renamed to [codominium-series](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/codominium-series) (without the first hyphen)?

  **Yes.** I've just done this, and edited the tag wiki to say CoDominium instead of Co-Dominium.

  **EDIT**: on the advice of user14111 (who's far more knowledgeable about 20th-century science fiction literature than I am), I renamed the tag to [codominium-universe](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/codominium-universe) instead. Note that this required no editing of posts: no front page was harmed in the making of this answer.

Comment: Wikipedia says that King David's Spaceship is also part of the Moties series, but some quick Duck Duck Going makes it look like it is marketed as a CoDominium book instead. Wikipedia also lists a poem and a short story as being part of the Moties series. Maybe the [tag:mote-series] tag wiki should only mention the three books you listed, and say that there are other related works in the CoDominium series.

Comment: @amarillo, *King David's Spaceship* has a passing reference (IIRC, it's a single sentence) to the events in *The Mote in God's Eye*.  Other than that, it's purely a CoDominium work.

Comment: The ISFDB calls it the [*Moties*](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?736) series, a subseries of the [*CoDominion Universe*](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?735) series. We should do likewise. So the correct answers are Yes, Yes, and No, make it codominion-universe-series.

Comment: I wrote a tag wiki for [tag:mote-series]. It might need to be updated if the tags get renamed to match the ISFDB.

Comment: @user14111 You have a good point, but [tag:condominium-universe-series] is too long to be a tag name.

Comment: @amarillo Oh, right. Well, I guess codominium-universe and for that matter moties would work just as well wouldn't they?

Comment: @user14111 I suppose so. You could write an answer proposing that and see what the voters think. I'm not sure why your old answer is gone. Although this question isn't getting many votes in the first place.

Comment: @amarillo  My "answer" was intended as a comment, but I typed it in the answer box by mistake. When I realized my mistake, I deleted the answer and copied it into the comment box.

Comment: @user14111 I just renamed the [tag:codominium-series] tag to [tag:codominium-universe]. You might like to edit the tag wiki for it, since you seem to know more about CoDominium than amarillo or I do.

Comment: @Randal'Thor I'm sorry if I gave you the impression that I know anything about that series. I read *The Mote in God's Eye* and that's all.

Comment: @user14111 That already means you know a lot more about it than I do, since I'd never even heard of it before seeing this meta post.